# How to view only MY posts on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

How can I see only **my** posts on Tumblr? I don't want to see pictures or whatever else I've re-blogged, just my posts. I'm asking this specifically because I’d rather not scroll through the millions of posts I have to view old pictures I have on there.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

1. Use [Tumblr Originals](http://www.studiomoh.com/fun/tumblr_originals/). Reblogs are hidden and only your original posts are shown. However, all your original posts are shown, regardless of its *type* (text, photo, audio, etc.).
2. Type `http://<username>.tumblr.com/archive/filter-by/text` on your address bar. However, all your text posts are shown, even the *reblogged* ones.

Pick your poison.

Answer (score 1):

From the front end, this is impossible unless you have tagged the posts appropriately.

Looking at [the API](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), it sounds like it *may* be possible to build a tool that would view a feed and filter on some of the returned `reblogged_` fields. (Note that the building of such a tool is out of scope for this site.)

Comment: There are at least two Mac apps that would help, one that expands on the limited web "dashboard" called - I don't know hy - Milk.

Answer (score 1):

I recently wrote a small [web app](http://jetblackcode.com/tumblrnotecounter) that does this and a couple other things too. There's a few really great sites out there that do similar things, but I wanted to make my own version with some extra features. It's called [Tumblr Note Counter](http://jetblackcode.com/tumblrnotecounter)

The app can:

- Count the total number of notes on **all** your original posts.
- Show you your top 9 most popular original posts.
- Find all of your original posts with over X notes (e.g. 50, or 1000, etc).

Just enter a Tumblr blog name to start it. If you want to see all of your posts, just type 0 in the note limit box and it will show everything.